# React native require images breaks with variables

Tags: react-native

How come this line works with no errors

```
var gicon = species[ii].color[0] ? require('../assets/gLight.jpg') : require('../assets/nLight.png');
```

while this line throws an error?

```
which_light = "gLight";
var gicon = species[ii].color[0] ? require('../assets/' + which_light + '.jpg') : require('../assets/nLight.png');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image names are resolved during packaging. There is a [section about it in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#static-image-resources). You can solve your problem by defining constants for the images:

```
const LIGHT_G = require('../assets/gLight.jpg');
const LIGHT_N = require('../assets/nLight.png');

which_light = LIGHT_G;
var gicon = species[ii].color[0] ? which_light : LIGHT_N;
```

You have to reference all possible images like this.