# How can I have a component load an asset at a path represented by props?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to build a component that loads a file from a path via `require()`. This path would be passed in via `props`. When I try this:

```
const asset = require({ this.props.filePath });
```

I get a build error (TransformError): **require() must have a single string literal argument**

Is there another method I could use to load an asset with the file path being represented as a `var`? Maybe there is a different parent/child relationship I could try that would accomplish the same thing? I feel like this is useful functionality. I am testing on iOS.

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: Are you declaring the variable inside of your react component?  If you're trying to declare your asset variable outside of your react component then you will not have access to props.

Comment: `require` *must* have a string literal, i.e. a phrase contained in quotes. It cannot be contained in a variable-- therefore what you are attempting is currently not possible. String literal => `"string literal"`, not string literal => `var str="string literal"; console.log(str);`

Comment: @Kevin_TA - Please use the "edit" button below your answer to edit your answer to the question you really want to ask.  Your current question has no answer other than, "you can't do that".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React native require images breaks with variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36857274/react-native-require-images-breaks-with-variables)